# How to launch an activity on phone call end?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app that allows the user to lend their phone to people who ask to use their phones for a phone call. It works with a EditText and Button.

Here's the phone call code:

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setEditText1((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1));
    button1.setOnClickListener(this); {}}


            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                EditText num=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String number = "tel:" +num.getText().toString().trim();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
```

What I want to do is make it so that when the guest ends their phone call, it goes to a password activity. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please reword this sentence: `I have a code that allows the user to lend their phone to people who ask to use their phones for a phone call.`

Comment: I meant app, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TelephonyManager` and `PhoneStateListener` and override `onCallStateChanged` so that you start your activity when the state changes to `CALL_STATE_IDLE`.